# Effecient MySQL SELECT for text in columns in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, full-table-scan

I have a large large table (InnoDB) that essentially has a location name with the location's latitude and longitude.  my query is something like

```
SELECT columns FROM table  
WHERE latitude BETWEEN latMin AND latMax
AND longitude BETWEEN longMin AND longMax
AND location LIKE '%mcdonalds%'
```

the only index is the primary index for the auto incrementing column.

I would prefer to use InnoDB so FULLTEXT isn't an option

One option I tried was adding indexes to the latitude and longitude, and doing

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE 
latitude BETWEEN latMin AND latMax
AND longitude BETWEEN longMin AND longMax
```

then i do

```
$stringOfIds = implode(",",$result);
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE id IN ($stringOfIds)
AND location LIKE '%mcdonalds%'
```

But it's not very scalable because the $result can have thousands of entries and takes too much memory

For now, I have resorted to a full table scan (the first query above) but it takes 0.5-1 seconds per query so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: afaik, full text index does not require unique values

Comment: There's nothing about a fulltext index that requires records by unique. It's just a way of doing more efficient text searching than `like '%blahblah%'` could ever be. A fulltext index cannot be unique in any case. Only a normal index can be made unique.

Comment: Ah got it.  But I would prefer to use InnoDB and InnoDb doesn't support FULLTEXT, right?

Answer (score 0):

The standard B-TREE index is not well suited to this sort of query. I'd recommend changing your design to use the geography type and then [creating a SPATIAL index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html). You can then use this index with [`MBRContains`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_mbrcontains) to quickly find all the points that lie within your bounding box.

Update: Creating a spatial index requires MyISAM as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the difference between your query and mine besides the column1,column2.  Also, InnoDB cannot use Spatial index, right?

Comment: @AndrewPark, Annoyingly no. If you want proper GIS support you'll have to switch to postgreSQL. Or use MyISAM, but that only has bounding rectangles.

Comment: @Andrew Park: Sorry didn't see that you already tried that. And yes you are right that you need to use MyISAM to add a SPATIAL index. I forgot about that. Perhaps you can store the spatial data in a separate table so that your master table can remain as InnoDB. You can use an ID to join the two tables.